# Right format to use sed in expect(TCL) exec involking?

Tags: string, replace, sed, tcl, expect

Linux expect snippet :

```
set info "IP address 2.2.2.2 mask x\n"

set OLD_INTERNET_IP "2.2.2.2"
set NEW_INTERNET_IP "1.1.1.1"

set newinfo  [exec echo $info | sed '{s/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/}']


send_user $info 
send_user $newinfo
```

What I am trying is to replace 2.2.2.2 in info to 1.1.1.1 and set to newinfo.

After hard trying in different format, the line `set newinfo  [exec echo $info | sed '{s/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/}']` is not working.

Can anyone give a hand? Thank you.

EDIT:
s/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/ above is a careless mistake, should be:
s/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/${NEW_INTERNET_IP}/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% set newinfo  [exec echo $info | sed '{s/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/}']
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

First, single quotes have absolutely no special meaning in Tcl, so remove them. The quoting characters in Tcl are double quotes and braces.
Second, you want to substitute the variables, so you can't use braces. Replace the braces with double quotes.
Third, you're replacing the old value with the old value. You meant:

```
% set newinfo  [exec echo $info | sed "s/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/${NEW_INTERNET_IP}/"]
IP address 1.1.1.1 mask x
```

Next, you can remove the `echo` by passing the Tcl variable to `sed` via its stdin ([ref](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm)):

```
% set newinfo  [exec sed "s/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/${NEW_INTERNET_IP}/" << $info]
IP address 1.1.1.1 mask x
```

Last, you don't need to `exec` out to sed at all:

```
% set newinfo [string map [list $OLD_INTERNET_IP $NEW_INTERNET_IP] $info]
IP address 1.1.1.1 mask x
```

[ref](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: thank you for your instruction. and apologize for the old new ip mistake

Comment: No apologies necessary. Typos happen. You did the right thing by asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about expect, but for sed you don't need the curly brackets. This works on the command line:

```
echo 2.2.2.2 | sed 's/2.2.2.2/1.1.1.1/'
```

If i use the curly brackets as you are i get:

```
$ echo 2.2.2.2 | sed '{s/2.2.2.2/1.1.1.1/}'
sed: command garbled: {s/2.2.2.2/1.1.1.1/}
```

so your expect command might work as:

```
exec echo $info | sed 's/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/'
```

If not let me know the actual output and errors.

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
    while executing
"exec echo $info | sed 's/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/'"
    invoked from within
"set newinfo  [exec echo $info | sed 's/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/${OLD_INTERNET_IP}/']"
    (file "aaa.exp" line 6)